# Android TagManager not getting default values

Tags: android, json, google-tag-manager

I am trying to implement the fairly new Android TagManager from Google. I can't seem to be able to load the default values.

I have created my default json file:

`assets/tagmanager/GTM-xxx.json`

Which looks like this:

`{ 'eulaTextVersion': '1' }`

I have also added this code to actually pull the default file if nothing is found on the server:

```
TagManager mTagManager = TagManager.getInstance(this);

        // The container is returned to containerFuture when available.
        ContainerOpener.openContainer(
            mTagManager,                            // TagManager instance.
            CONTAINER_ID,                           // Tag Manager Container ID.
            OpenType.PREFER_NON_DEFAULT,            // Prefer not to get the default container, but stale is OK.
            null,                                   // Time to wait for saved container to load (ms). Default is 2000ms.
            new ContainerOpener.Notifier() {        // Called when container loads.
              @Override
              public void containerAvailable(Container container) {
                // Handle assignment in callback to avoid blocking main thread.
                mContainer = container;
              }
            }
        );

int eulaTextVersion = (int) mContainer.getDouble("eulaTextVersion");
```

However, when I debug, my `int eulaTextVersion` is always zero, I can never get it to 1 like it should be from my default json. Could someone please help me out and show me where I am going wrong?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Google Tag Manager already downloaded first version for you. First version is probably empty. Just make next version with "Values" that contain "eulaTextVersion" and "Publish" it.

If you do not know how to set those values on your Google Tag Manger account look at: http://youtu.be/Xe8W5w68BRg?t=8m26s

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using quotation for numerical values. Try the following instead

```
{ 'eulaTextVersion': 1 }
```